# NoMethodError in rails even though correct gem is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, rubygems, nomethoderror

In my gemfile, I have `gem 'stringex'`. After running `bundle install`, I added a path helper and am using a method that is from stringex. I should be able to use `to_url` directly on a string, like the example in the stringex readme: `"simple English".to_url => "simple-english"`.

However, when I try to use the method .to_url on a string in my path helper, I get:

`undefined method 'to_url' for "fake title":String`

My helper method looks something like:

```
module PostsHelper
  def post_path(post)
      "/posts/#{post.id}/#{post.title.to_url}"
  end
end
```

Comment: seems like your gem is not installed. did you try manually adding reference to that gem?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can try is running `bundle exec irb` and then trying to `require "stringex"`. If you can't require the gem in properly, then it's not installed in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `require 'stringex'` to the top of your `posts_helper.rb` file.